# Swift more than one behaviour in the same UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I add a custom `collectionViewLayout` to `CollectionView`. I have 6 cells and I pass the next item with default animation style. But when I pass the last cell I want to make an animation as PageAnimation(custom). I add the `collectionViewLayout` in the `viewDidLoad` but it effects all cells.

```
let layout = AnimatedCollectionViewLayout()
layout.animator = PageAttributesAnimator()
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

How can I use 2 different layout types in one `CollectionView` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        for cell: UICollectionViewCell in clcView.visibleCells {
            let indexPath: IndexPath? = clcView.indexPath(for: cell)
            if let indexPath = indexPath {
                print("\(indexPath)")
                if indexPath.row >= 2 {
                    let layout = AnimatedCollectionViewLayout()
                    layout.animator = PageAttributesAnimator()
                    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
                    clcView.collectionViewLayout = layout
                }
                else {
                    let layout = AnimatedCollectionViewLayout()
                    layout.animator = RotateInOutAttributesAnimator()
                    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
                    clcView.collectionViewLayout = layout
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works with partially. Sometimes effect all collectionview sometimes not.